# How to find min and max values of a dataframe within x rolling rows without a loop?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have this dataframe that looks like that:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [5, 8],
        [8, 10],
        [3, 15],
        [16, 20],
        [12, 21],
        [5, 9],
        [10, 12],
        [20, 22],
        [4, 10],
        [7, 13],
        [9, 15],
        [6, 9],
    ],
    columns=list("lh"),
)
```

I would like to know the min and max within x previous and forward rows for each row but without using a loop, as the dataframe is quite large, and it takes a long time.

I have this function that works:

```py
def pivotid(df1, l, n1, n2):  # n1 n2 before and after candle L
    if l - n1 < 0 or l + n2 >= len(df1):
        return 0

    pividlow = 1
    pividhigh = 1
    for i in range(l - n1, l + n2 + 1):
        if df1.l[l] > df1.l[i]:
            pividlow = 0
        if df1.h[l] < df1.h[i]:
            pividhigh = 0

    if pividlow and pividhigh:
        return 3
    elif pividlow:
        return 1
    elif pividhigh:
        return 2
    else:
        return 0
```

Here's how I call it:

```py
df['pivot'] = df.apply(lambda x: pivotid(df, x.name, 2, 2), axis=1)
```

Here's the expected result:

```
     l   h  pivot
0    5   8      0
1    8  10      0
2    3  15      1
3   16  20      0
4   12  21      2
5    5   9      1
6   10  12      0
7   20  22      2
8    4  10      1
9    7  13      0
10   9  15      0
11   6   9      0
```

Do you think that there's a way to achieve that without using a for loop with pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the dataframe you provided, here is one way to do it using Pandas [rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html):

```py
df["pivot"] = (
    (df["l"] == df["l"].rolling(window=5, center=True).min()).astype(int) 
    + (df["h"] == df["h"].rolling(window=5, center=True).max()).astype(int) * 2
)
```

Then:

```py
print(df)
# Output
     l   h  pivot
0    5   8      0
1    8  10      0
2    3  15      1
3   16  20      0
4   12  21      2
5    5   9      1
6   10  12      0
7   20  22      2
8    4  10      1
9    7  13      0
10   9  15      0
11   6   9      0
```

Comment: Hi Laurent,
Thank you for this very effective solution!
One last thing, sometimes the rows before and after the tested row can be different. In my example it would be:

df['pivot'] = df.apply(lambda x: pivotid(df, x.name, 5, 2), axis=1) where we check 5 rows before and 2 rows after the tested row in the loop.

Do you think that this would be possible using rolling?

Comment: I think I got it. For 5 rows back and 2 rows after it would be:
candles["pivot"] = (
    (candles["l"] == candles["l"].rolling(window=7, center=False, closed='both').min().shift(-2)).astype(int)
    + (candles["h"] == candles["h"].rolling(window=7, center=False, closed='both').max().shift(-2)).astype(int) * 2
)

Comment: Indeed, it seems to be the right thing to do. Cheers.